# How do I save user preferences for my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The question title pretty much gives it away - I'd like my app to remember a few things. It's some sort of calculator, so it should save the last used values and some user selectable settings.

Basically I'd like to save a handful of floats and BOOLs and load them again the next time the app loads.

What's the best and easiest way to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

One of the easiest ways would be saving it in the [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

Setting:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setObject:value 
                 forKey:key];
// – setBool:forKey:
// – setFloat:forKey:  
// in your case 
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Getting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];

– boolForKey:
```

and

`– floatForKey:` in your case.

Comment: `-setValue:forKey:` and `-valueForKey`, respectively, are also fine. Moreover, the `standardUserDefaults` are always backed up when an iDevice is synched. This is great if you want to include in-app purchases.

Comment: Note that the documentation for the `synchronize` method states that the method is "unnecessary and shouldn't be used".

Answer (score 7):

Besides the very good NSUserDefaults approach, there is another easy way to store data from an NSArray,NSDictionary or NSData in a file. You can use these methods as well:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

respectively (for a NSDictionary):

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

you just have to give a valid path to a location. According to the iOS Application Programming Guide, the /Library/Caches directory would be the best place to store data that you need to persist between app launches. (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW12).))

In order to store/load a dictionary from a filed called "managers" in your document directoy you could use these methods:

```
-(void) loadDictionary {
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //create a destination file name to write the data :
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/managers", cacheDirectory];
    NSDictionary* panelLibraryContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
    if (panelLibraryContent != nil) {
        // load was successful do something with the data...
    } else {
        // error while loading the file
    }   
}

-(void) storeDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dictionaryToStore {
    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    //make a file name to write the data to using the
    //cache directory:
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/managers", cacheDirectory];

    if (dictionaryToStore != nil) {
        [dictionaryToStore writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Anyway this approach is very limited and you have to spend a lot of extra work if you want to store more complex data. In that case the CoreData API is very very handy.

Comment: User preferences are not really documents.

Comment: @SK9 : I pointed out in the first line that I'm only showing an alternative to the NSUserDefaults approach. Don't thing it's fair/necessary to down vote a valid alternative.

Comment: eg. From your link to the docs -- "If your application creates large data files or **files that change frequently**, you should consider storing them in the Application Home/Library/Caches directory and not in the <Application_Home>/Documents directory. Backing up large data files can slow down the backup process significantly. The same is true for files that change regularly. Placing these files in the Caches directory prevents them from being backed up (in iOS 2.2 and later) during every sync operation."

Comment: @SK9: ahh thx, sorry I was getting you wrong. Changed my answer accordingly. You were right!

Answer (score 7):

## In Swift:

**Setting**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(value, forKey: key)

// userDefaults.setFloat(12.34, forKey: "myFloatKey")
// userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "myBoolKey")
```

Note that for iOS 8 and later, calling `userDefaults.synchronize()` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589162/ios-setobject-vs-synchronize/25590044#25590044).

**Getting**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let value = userDefaults.objectForKey(key) {
    print(value)
}
```

Note that `userDefaults.boolForKey` and `userDefaults.floatForKey` both return non optional values, so they would never be `nil` (only `false` or `0.0`).

## Further reading

- [NSUserDefaults — A Swift Introduction](http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

Comment: Have been renamed to `UserDefaults.standard`

Comment: @Hykilpikonna, thank you. Feel free to edit the content of the answer. I'm not actively updating my Swift answers since I've been focused on Flutter recently.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for  [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 / Linux**

Apparently something has changed. Now there's the `UserDefault` class.
Check these links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults