# Use didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to save preferences

Tags: ios, objective-c

there is a notification in my view controller that listens for preference changes and then updates the sound settings. When I change the sound settings and then kill the app, the prefs don't persist.

I need to check those prefs and set the sounds settings based on the persisted prefs on app launch

Can I do this from the app delegate, if so, how?

Here is the notification

```
- (void)preferencesDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSMutableArray *changedPreferences = note.object;
    if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localPlayUISounds"]) {
        [FHSSound setUISoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayUISounds];
    }
    else if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localPlayAlertSounds"]) {
        [FHSSound setAlertSoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayAlertSounds];
    }
    else if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localEnablesDNDWhenDrivingCar"]) {
        [self startMonitoringLocationIfEnabled];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use NSUserDefaults for this. 
The system keeps a set of defaults for your app. You just have to add the values when they are set, and load them again in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

To save a value, when the user changes it:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"playSound"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To load it at startup (in the app delegate):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
bool playSound = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"playSound"];
```

One extra detail: on the first run of the app those values will return NO, so you want to detect that.
I would do something like this on the app delegate:

```
int runCount = (int)[userDefaults integerForKey:@"runCount"];
if (!runCount)
{
    //first run, save the predefined values
}
else
{
    //not first run, load the previously saved values
}

runCount++;
[userDefaults setInteger:runCount forKey:@"runCount"];
```

Comment: Okay So would I be implementing NSUserDefaults within the NSNotification method?

Comment: Yes, when you get notified and change a setting, save the value to NSUserDefaults. Then when the app starts again, you load the saved values in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. It should work :)

Comment: I'm getting a warning that "playSound is an unused variable" in the app delegate.

Comment: so I used localPlayUISounds instead but still the same warning and still not reading the value. Any ideas?

Comment: bool playSound is an unused variable because you are not using it afterwards, is that it? the key can be anything you want, as long as it's the same you use for saving it.

Comment: what is the value of the variable after loading it? always 0?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3566178/1325032) about saving user preferences.

Once your preferences are persisted, then you can reload them whenever the application starts by providing your own implementation of

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

You might also consider registering a handler for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` event if you want to restore the sound settings whenever the application returns to the foreground even if it wasn't killed between activations.

Answer (score 0):

The data was already persisting, I just had to find a way for the app to launch off of the persisted data. Here is what I did

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setSoundPreferences];
}
```

The notification is set to listen for the change in prefs

```
- (void)preferencesDidChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
NSMutableArray *changedPreferences = note.object;
if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localPlayUISounds"]) {
[FHSSound setUISoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayUISounds];
}
else if ([changedPreferences containsObject:@"localPlayAlertSounds"]) {
[FHSSound setAlertSoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayAlertSounds];
}
```

and lastly setting the preferences at launch

```
#pragma mark (launch)
- (void)setSoundPreferences
{
[FHSSound setUISoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayUISounds];
[FHSSound setAlertSoundsEnabled:PREFS.localPlayAlertSounds];
}
```