# Use score from GameScene in second view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on an app and I am have `GameScene, GameViewController, and a ResetViewController`. I have my scoring method set up in the gameScene, the problem is I need to use the score from my GameScene for a label in my ResetViewController.

This is what I have

In My GameScene

```
var score: Int = 0
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()


//the scoreLabel works fine on the game scene
score++
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
```

I am Needing to display the score on this UiLabel on my resetViewController

```
    @IBOutlet weak var YourScore: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value using NSUserDefaults. That way the val will be stored for any further use as well.

How to save to user defaults can be found here [How do I save user preferences for my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566140/how-do-i-save-user-preferences-for-my-iphone-app)

Comment: I tried the NSUserDefaults but if the person playing doesn't score it will just say whatever there last score was

Comment: Set and save the score to 0 when starting the game.