# How To Make An Int Score on Another Page in Xcode

Tags: xcode4

I am trying to make an int on another page for my game. I tried This:

"score = score + 1;"

```
"scoretext.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];"
```

But every time I switch out of that view controller and come back the score is at Zero! How do you save the Number so when you come back it is not gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should have a look at user defaults in objective C so that you can save the data for local user game even when the game is sent to background you can have track to the score or also you can store the current user state

you can have a look at this in the links below
[How do I save user preferences for my iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566140/how-do-i-save-user-preferences-for-my-iphone-app)
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSUserDefaults.html